# Is it possible to create Android app based on webview accessing the https urls

Tags: https, android-webview, x509certificate, httpsurlconnection, sslsocketfactory

I have one class which is using webview to open this url:https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in and I have created local certificate using this below code..I am successfully getting response of 200 but my question is how I proceed to display the webpage to user.
I have tested this code:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    public final String TAG = WebViewFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebView webView;

    public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    public static final String DEFAULT_CHARSET_NAME = "UTF-8";

    public WebViewFragment() {

    }

    public static WebViewFragment newInstance() {
        return new WebViewFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_webview_fragment, container, false);

        initGlobal(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void initGlobal(View view) {
        webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        //MyBrowser is a custom class which extends Webviewclient which loads the given url in the webview
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

//        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
//        webView.loadUrl("https://www.github.com");
//        webView.loadUrl("https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in/");

        try {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(getActivity().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.newcertificate));
            Certificate ca;
            try {
                ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
            } finally {
                caInput.close();
            }

            // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
            String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);


            // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
            String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
            tmf.init(keyStore);

            // Create a SSLContext with the certificate
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

            // Create a HTTPS connection
            URL url = new URL("https://eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in");
            HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

            InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
            int lastResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            Log.e(TAG, "response code=" + lastResponseCode);

            if (lastResponseCode == 200) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Response code==" + lastResponseCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            copyInputStreamToOutputStream(in, System.out, 2048, true, true);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception========" + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void copyInputStreamToOutputStream(InputStream from, OutputStream to, int bufferSize, boolean closeInput, boolean closeOutput) {
        try {
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int offset = 0;
            byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

            while ((bytesRead = from.read(data, offset, bufferSize)) > 0) {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                to.write(data, offset, bytesRead);
                Log.e(TAG, "Copied " + totalBytesRead + " bytes");
            }
            closeStreams(from, to, closeInput, closeOutput);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            closeStreams(from, to, closeInput, closeOutput);
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public void closeStreams(InputStream from, OutputStream to, boolean closeInput, boolean closeOutput) {
        try {
            if (to != null)
                to.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (closeInput && from != null)
                from.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if (closeOutput && to != null)
                to.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your exact question? Is it "how to display webview in UI" or "can webview load HTTPS" or "can webview load HTTPS page whose cert is not trusted by the OS and I want it to validate the cert using the custom CA store" ?

Comment: @jakub.g actually I just want to load the above url in webview and its showing blank screen.Any ways I found the way I have to use onReceivedSslError method to bypass this issue. I was misguided that I need custom keystore to access url also.

Comment: It if shows blank screen it means most likely https cert can't be validated for some reason. Note that you should not do just `handler.proceed()` in `onReceivedSslError` in a production app as that is defeating the purpose of HTTPS as it makes the app prone to man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: @jakub.g But I am not calling any https web service, just opening the url by showing one dialog to user which alerts user if they wish to proceed.If I follow this my app will be rejected? I have got this solution only on stackoverflow

Comment: If you show the dialog it's better than blindly accepting the invalid cert. But still the https cert validation has failed for some reason: either 1) the device does not have proper CA cert, or 2) your cert is invalid (maybe self-signed etc.). Does the page load fine in normal browsers like Chrome? If so, most likely the problem is that the server doesn't send the complete cert chain. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in&latest

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that the server doesn't send complete certificate chain (doesn't send intermediary certificates)

See here:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=eaadhaar.uidai.gov.in&latest

Click `Certification Paths` and you will see `Extra download` next to `GeoTrust SSL CA - G3`.

This is a WebView-specific thing: it does not fetch intermediary certs (regular browsers like Chrome or Firefox either do it, or cache the certs they've seen while user was browsing some other pages)

You need to contact the server admin/ops to send all the intermediary certs.
We've had similar issues with our apps and it was solved by sending all the intermediary certs in the SSL handshake.

Overriding `onReceivedSslError` is an insecure way of fixing the problem and should not be used in production apps. Treat it as development-only tool.